# How to make confidence intervals "run off" the edge of a forestplot in R, so that other plots retain detail?

Tags: r, data-visualization, graph-visualization, r-forestplot

I am visualizing a bunch of effects on different species in a forestplot using the R package jtools. One model has huuuuge confidence intervals compared to the rest, so I end up losing detail on the effect sized for other models(see image below).[image: a forest plot with huge CI for one model]

As you can see, the elephant CI is blowing out the graph to a different scale and the effect sizes for other species are hard to discern.

Here is my code:

```
library("jtools")
plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3, scale = TRUE, colors = "Rainbow", model.names = c("Apes", "Elephants", "Pangolins"))
```

Is there a way to tell this function to let the wide confidence interval lines to "fall off" the edge of the graph, so that the scale can be appropriate to see the effect sizes for other models?

I'm an R newbie, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I'd like it to look more like this graph in the end - where you can actually see the effect sizes of all models. [image: Another forestplot, but in this one you can better see all effect sizes for all species]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jtools::plot_summs` returns a `ggplot` object, so it can be easily adjusted

```
class(plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3)) # using the example given in ?plot_summs
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

For setting the ranges manually, you can use `ggplot2::coord_cartesian`

```
library(ggplot2)
plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-250, 250))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but when I enter coordinates, it doesn't change the scale, and it removes all the model names. Here is how I modified my code:

plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5, fit6, fit8, fit9, scale = TRUE, colors = "Rainbow", model.names = c("Apes", "Monkeys", "Sm. Duiker", "Lg. Duiker", "Carnivores", "Pangolins", "Squirrels", "Elephants") + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.1, 0.1)))

Comment: @Tiff-D The `+ coord_cartesian` should go after the output of `plot_summs`. If I copied your code correctly, you added this as argument to the `plot_summs` function. (`+` is the ggplot2 pipe operator, so you modify the object created by plot_summs before it is finally plotted)

Comment: `plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5, fit6, fit8, fit9, scale = TRUE,  colors = "Rainbow", 
model.names = c("Apes", "Monkeys", "Sm. Duiker", "Lg. Duiker", "Carnivores", "Pangolins", "Squirrels", "Elephants")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.1, 0.1))`